# Toggle between DIV Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngualrJS. And I am wondering, if ther is some way to toggle between different DIV's.

Let's say, in I have a menu, and by clicking on it, I would like to close current DIV, and open a new one.

A the moment if I one dive is opened and Im clicking at the another one it also appear.

Does any one have an idea, hot to handel this out?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="Menu in Menus">
                    <a class="" href="#" ng-click="show=toggle(Menu)">
                        {{Menu.id}}
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="Menu in Menus" ng-show="Menu.show">
             <h2>
                     {{Menu.text}}
                </h2>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).

controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Menus = [{
        id: 1,
        text: "This is first DIV!!!",
        show: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "This is second DIV!!!",
        show: false
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "This is third DIV!!!",
        show: false
    }];

    $scope.toggle = function (Menu) {
        Menu.show = !Menu.show;        
        return Menu.show;

    };


}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide all menus and only show the selected one, change your toggle function like this :

```
$scope.toggle = function (Menu) {
    $scope.Menus.forEach(function(m) {
        m.show = (Menu==m);
    });
};
```

### Update:

here's a better alternative, less and faster code :

you can get rid of the show property on your data and change the toggle function to

```
$scope.toggle = function (Menu) {
    $scope.activeMenu = Menu.id;
};
```

and change your `ng-show` to `ng-show="Menu.id==(activeMenu || 1)"`

here's a working example : https://refork.codicode.com/xc23

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

I was also keep trying, and came up, to some thing simular, can you comment please, what do yiu think about my solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/djonkwt/x40ure3f/2/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a function that sets the current menu to hide. Then it would show the preferred menu.

```js
$scope.toggle = function toggle(menu) {
  angular.forEach($scope.Menus, function(menuIndex) {
    menuIndex.show = false;
  })
  menu.show = true;
}
```

Did I understand your question correctly?